# Is a name of a fictional character, location or universe free to use if it is not trademarked?

Tags: united-states, trademark

After searching on USPTO names of characters fron Dota 2 and Warcraft, I found that most names are  not trademarked. Does this means these names are free to use as a software name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under US law, trademarks are only protected if they are "used in commerce". In general this means the mark is used to describe or label a product or service, or to advertise it.

Note that words and images used in this way may get a degree of trademark protection even if they are not registered. Proof of use in commerce is sufficient to grant this protection.

However, the names of characters are not usually used as identifications of a product or service, nor as designations of source. If they are not so used, they do not have trademark protection.

If a reasonable person would be led by the use of a character name to incorrectly believe that the product had been authorized, sponsored, or endorsed by the creator of the character or a related entity, then that use might constitute an infringement. But usually this would not be the case.

For example, a software company calling itself "SauronWare" and distributing a word processor called "SauronWriter" would probably not infringe on the intelelctual property of the Tolkien Estate.

But trademark  law can be complex, and a would-be user wouldf be wise to consult a trademark lawyer.

Note also that song, book, and story titles, character names, and other short phrases are not subject to copyright protection under US law (see Copyright Office Circular 33.)