# Can I use the name "Guybrush" in a videogame I create?

Tags: intellectual-property, video-games

As the question states. Can I use the name Guybrush for a character in my upcoming videogame?

Also does it make any difference if this name is used for my main character or just some side character that is insignificant to the game?

How can I find out such info for myself?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: For context: "Guybrush Threepwood" is the protagonist of the Monkey Island games. Made by Lucas Arts, which are now renamed Lucasfilm Games and were acquired by Disney.

Comment: This information needs to be made part of the question.

Comment: Is the name trademarked? And [see this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/79880/is-a-name-of-a-fictional-character-location-or-universe-free-to-use-if-it-is-no).